# Add a tick to top x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, multiple-axes, x-axis

I do not really understand why this code is not working

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Vg_vec, sigma_i)
ax.set_xlabel('$V_\mathrm{g}$ ($\mathrm{V}}$)')
ax.set_ylabel('$\sigma_\mathrm{i}$ ($\mathrm{C/m^2}$)')

peaks, _ = find_peaks(sigma_i, height=0.006415)
plt.axvline(Vg_vec[peaks], color='red')

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(Vg_vec[peaks])
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')
```

My result:

[image: Plot]

There should be a red tick in the top x axis.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3JtX.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue with your code is twofold:

1. By using `twiny` instead of `secondary_axis`, the upper x-axis will be different to the bottom one, and I assume you want them to be the same. That's extra work to fix, so I used `secondary_axis` in my example.
2. This is something I don't know why it happens, but it has happened to me before. When supplying the tick values, the first one is always "ignored", so you have to supply two or more values. I used `0`, but you can use anything.

Here's my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Vg_vec, sigma_i)
ax.set_xlabel('$V_\mathrm{g}$ ($\mathrm{V}}$)')
ax.set_ylabel('$\sigma_\mathrm{i}$ ($\mathrm{C/m^2}$)')

peaks, _ = find_peaks(sigma_i, height=None)
plt.axvline(Vg_vec[peaks], color='red')

ax2 = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x', color='red')
ax2.set_xticks([0, *Vg_vec[peaks]], minor=False)
```

And the resulting plot:

[image: Resulting plot]